# Meixner polynomial Cosh(x) and Sinh(x)^2 expansion

Tags: calculus

I am trying to use Meixner polynomials to expand some elementary functions as $\cos$ and other trigonometric functions but to get the coefficients of the expansion depending on its orthogonal measures, in the somebook I see the following expansion XE:

$$\cosh (x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{1-e}\right)^{-n} (c-1)^{-n} c^n \binom{-B}{n} \left(\frac{(c-e) (e c-1)}{(c-1)^2}\right)^{-B-n} \left(\left(\frac{c-e}{c-1}\right)^{B+n}+e^{B+i \pi  n} \left(\frac{e c-1}{c-1}\right)^{B+n}\right) \, _2F_1\left(-n,-x;B;\frac{c-1}{c}\right)$$
and
$$\sinh ^2(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{4} \left(e^2-1\right)^n (c-1)^{-n} c^n \binom{-B}{n} \left(\frac{\left(c-e^2\right) \left(e^2 c-1\right)}{(c-1)^2}\right)^{-B-n} \left(e^{2 B} \left(\frac{e^2 c-1}{c-1}\right)^{B+n}+e^{i \pi  n} \left(\frac{c-e^2}{c-1}\right)^{B+n}\right) \, _2F_1\left(-n,-x;B;\frac{c-1}{c}\right)$$
I tried to calculate some values and it seems to work but I have not proofs ??

Comment: A reference for those (like me) that not have been introduced to these polynomials : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meixner_polynomials

Comment: In the "somebook" : what are you meaning by this ? Could you  indicate the source-book where you have found such a formula ?